# What went wrong with my definition of angle theta and distance in my python code?

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate a particle under the central force $a_c = - k_r r^n \hat r$

however, I am encountering the error that my angle theta would be divided by zero sometimes

```
 theta = np.arctan((r_US[1]-y_0)/(r_US[0]-x_0))
```

as well as the invalid value error for my definition of my distance

```
distance = np.sqrt((r_US[0]-x_0) + (r_US[1] - y_0))
```

what would be a better definition suited for the python code? Thanks for the answers, below is the complete code

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["animation.html"] = 'jshtml'
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interactive

def MotionAnimation4(xstart,ystart,vxstart,vystart, n, k): #4
    

    xMin = 0.
    xMax = 5.
    yMin = 0.
    yMax = 5.
    
    x_0 = 2.5
    y_0 = 2.5 #defining the center of the circle
    
    
    def UpdatedState(r_US, v_US, a_US, Delta_t_US):
        distance = np.sqrt((r_US[0]-x_0)**2 + (r_US[1] - y_0)**2) #updating the distance to the center of the circle
        theta = np.arctan((r_US[1]-y_0)/(r_US[0]-x_0)) #defining angle relative to the center of the circle
        r_US = r_US + v_US * Delta_t_US
        a_x = -k * (distance**n) * np.cos(theta) 
        a_y = -k * (distance**n) * np.sin(theta)
        central_acceleration = np.array([[a_x, a_y]]) #defining central acceleration in cartesian coordinate
        
        if r_US[0] > xMax:
            r_US[0] = xMax - (r_US[0] - xMax)
            v_US[0] = -v_US[0]
        if r_US[0] < xMin:
            r_US[0] = xMin - (r_US[0] - xMin)
            v_US[0] = -v_US[0]
        if r_US[1] > yMax:
            r_US[1] = yMax - (r_US[1] - yMax)
            v_US[1] = -v_US[1]
        if r_US[1] < yMin:
            r_US[1] = yMin - (r_US[1] - yMin)
            v_US[1] = -v_US[1]
        
        a_US = central_acceleration 
        
        v_US = v_US + a_US * Delta_t_US 
        
        return r_US, v_US, a_US


    Delta_t = 0.05
    NumFrames = 100
    Frames = np.arange(NumFrames)

    xStart = xstart
    yStart = ystart

    vxStart = vxstart
    vyStart = vystart

    r = np.array([[xStart , yStart]])
    v = np.array([[vxStart , vyStart]])
    a = np.array([[0, 0]])
    
    for i in Frames:
        rnew, vnew, anew = UpdatedState(r[-1], v[-1], a[-1], Delta_t)
        r = np.vstack((r,rnew))
        v = np.vstack((v,vnew))
        a = np.vstack((a, anew))
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    dot, = plt.plot([],[],'-ro')

    def InitAniPlot():
        ax.axis([xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax])
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        return dot,

    def UpdatedAniPlot(i):
        dot.set_data(r[i,0], r[i,1])
        return dot,


    ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig,UpdatedAniPlot, frames = Frames, init_func = InitAniPlot)
    
    return ani

MotionAnimation4(2.5, 4., 1., 1., 2., 2)
```

p.s how would I apply latex for formulas in this stack exchange?

Comment: Look up `math.atan2(dy, dx)`.  It returns a correct angle as long as dx and dy are not both zero.

Comment: May I ask further why np.arctan didn't work in my case? To be more specific, the dx part wouldn't have been zero in any case (I think).

Comment: @Rico only specific stackexchange sites support latex. S.O. does not

Comment: Also, you might have forgotten squares in your distance

Comment: @AndreySobolev you are right, thanks

Comment: While you're looking up math.atan2, also look up math.hypot. That will save you from forgetting squares. :)

Comment: @TurePålsson Thank you, will do

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
theta = np.arctan((r_US[1]-y_0)/(r_US[0]-x_0))
```

with

```
theta = np.arctan2((r_US[1]-y_0), (r_US[0]-x_0))
```

and the code worked as intended